# How to merge GoogleNet and ResNet using keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to merge the two pretrained models GoogleNet and ResNet. I only have transfer learning codes for these two models:
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')

```
# useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('Images/Train/*')

for layer in base_model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set1 = train_datagen1.flow_from_directory('Images/Train',
                                             target_size = (150, 150),
                                             batch_size = 27,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set1 = test_datagen1.flow_from_directory('Images/Test',
                                        target_size = (150, 150),
                                        batch_size = 27,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

x = layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(base_model.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

inc_history = model.fit(training_set1, validation_data = test_set1, 
epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=len(training_set1),validation_steps=len(test_set1))


from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
base_model_2 = ResNet50(input_shape=(150, 150,3), include_top=False, weights="imagenet")

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('Images/Train/*')

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Images/Train',
                                             target_size = (150, 150),
                                             batch_size = 27,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Images/Test',
                                        target_size = (150, 150),
                                        batch_size = 27,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D

base_model_2 = Sequential()
base_model_2.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='max'))
base_model_2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

base_model_2.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['acc'])

#keras.utils.plot_model(base_model_2, "my_first_model.png")

resnet_history = base_model_2.fit(training_set, validation_data = test_set, 
epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),validation_steps=len(test_set))
```

Can someone please guide me on how to merge these two pretrained models?
-------------------------------------------------------------------
#Addition of merge model code and error

```
   inputs = keras.Input(shape = training_set.image_shape)
   m_1 = base_model(inputs)
   m_2 = base_model_2(inputs)

   outputs = tf.concat([m_1,m_2], axis = 0)
   new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Error code:
 InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in 
 _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
 1811   try:
 -> 1812     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
 1813   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for '{{node 
concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32] 
(inception_v3/mixed10/concat_2, sequential_13/dense_43/Sigmoid, 
concat_1/axis)' 
with input shapes: [?,3,3,2048], [?,1], [].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in 
_create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
1813   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
1814     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1815     raise ValueError(str(e))
1816 
1817   return c_op

ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for '{{node concat_1}} = 
ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](inception_v3/mixed10/concat_2, 
sequential_13/dense_43/Sigmoid, concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: 
[?,3,3,2048], [?,1], [].
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by merging 2 pre-trained models? You can instead fine-tune one of the model.

Comment: @YosiPramajaya I am actually trying to merge the models itself instead of fine tuning it.

Comment: You can use Keras functional API. I answered similar question like this, try to see if it's what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644565/merge-sequential-models-in-keras/64645883#64645883

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link
i tried the following code:
inputs = keras.Input(shape = training_set.image_shape)
m_1 = base_model(inputs)
m_2 = base_model_2(inputs)

outputs = tf.concat([m_1,m_2], axis = 0)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
but i got value error (ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for '{{node concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](inception_v3/mixed10/concat_2, sequential_13/dense_43/Sigmoid, concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [?,3,3,2048], [?,1], [].)

Comment: It's really hard to see the code / error log in comment. Can you edit and put it in the question instead?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya I have edit my question and added the code for merge model and the error received while executing it