# Merge Sequential models in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to concatenate these two models in my project, I am quite new in this field so please don't judge me hard. So here is the code.

```
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(10, input_dim=df2_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(50, input_dim=df2_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(10, input_dim=df2_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model2.add(Dense(df2_y.shape[1],activation='softmax'))
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
monitor2 = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, 
                        patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto',
                           restore_best_weights=True)
model2.fit(df2_x_train,df2_y_train,validation_data=(df2_x_test, df2_y_test),
          callbacks=[monitor2],verbose=2,epochs=1000)
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=df_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=df_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=df_x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dense(df_y.shape[1],activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, 
                        patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto',
                           restore_best_weights=True)
model.fit(df_x_train,df_y_train,validation_data=(df_x_test, df_y_test),
          callbacks=[monitor],verbose=2,epochs=1000)
```

And after the model obtained, I want to make predictions.

So I have two datasets, one for DOS-portmap attacks, and one for DOS-UDP attacks.

If I want to predict something, how can I distinguish between these two?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keras functional API for this. Model is basically same like a layer, it's callable, and can be included in another model.

For example, this is greatly simplified version of concatenating results from 2 Models:

```
inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
y_1 = model1(inputs)
y_2 = model2(inputs)
outputs = tf.concat([y_1, y_2], axis=0)

new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Of course, you want to make sure that the outputs is your desired result. Therefore, the key is in the last layer, what kind of operations you want to do with the values you get from y_1 and y_2.

Some use custom layer for this, you can use that as well. You can look for more article about Functional API and Custom Layer in Tensorflow doc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330534/merge-multiple-models-in-keras-tensorflow          -: can you help me with that!